# Why text, innerText, innerHTML return empty in selenium

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
<div class="SdTitle-sc-iwgcvh dmugDV title">#24 Information Revolution</div>
```

I want to get the text in this div. I was using this code:

```
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]").get_attribute("innerText")
```

But it returns an empty string, I tried `text()`, `get_attribute("innerText")`, `get_attribute("innerHTML")`. None of them works.

The element can be found by selenium.
I also found this element with the xpath in chrome, which means the xpath is correct.

If I tried `get_attribute('outerHTML')`, it returns

```
<div class="SdTitle-sc-iwgcvh dmugDV title"></div>
```

This is so strange.

I searched on Chrome that the div with these classes only has 1.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you share HTML code in text format here? or if URL is public then please share

Comment: Here is the URL, https://www.apeuni.com/zh-CN/practice/essays/24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `text()` instead of `.text`

There is no such thing called `get_attribute("innerText")`

**Update 1 :**

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='SdTitle']"))).text
print(el)
```

Comment: I suspect the `#` makes selenium ignores the text.

Comment: I can not locate this in chrome `/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]`

Comment: is that element seen after login ?

Comment: Chrome Developer Tool / Elements (command F, input the full xpath)/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232811/discussion-between-cruisepandey-and-shark-deng).

Comment: Working solution `el = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='SdTitle']"))).text
print(el)` presented by @cruisepandey

Answer (score 2):

The attribute is called `innerHTML` Read here for more details: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

```
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".SdTitle-sc-iwgcvh.dmugDV.title").text
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".SdTitle-sc-iwgcvh.dmugDV.title").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Print to check the output.
A little explanation: `.` is used for a class name. If there are few classes in a one html tag, you can make a locator of them divided by dot, without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='SdTitle-sc-iwgcvh dmugDV title']").get_attribute("innertext")
```

If not use text to get the text value from the element like this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='SdTitle-sc-iwgcvh dmugDV title']").text
```

Comment: This is not correct https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue, I found in Protractor. I too, used different ways to get the text using .`getText()`, `innerText`, `innerHtml` etc. But finally I tried to use `tagName` locator to retrieve the text. Might be below code is helps to you to implement in Selenium. Note: Below code is for Protractor

```
element(by.tagName('mat-chip')).getText().then(function (rowAtt) {
                console.log("Attributed Under Row Group-"+rowAtt)
                expect(rowAtt).toBe(attValues.explore.attributeValues.rowAttributes[i], 'Attribute value is not matching');
                if (rowAtt) {
                    exploreModule.attributeCheckBox().click();
                } else {
                    console.log("attribute checkbox is not present");
                }
            })
```